# Binding Monorail RadioFields to GenericLists

Tags: castle-monorail, castle

I have the following object which I bind to a Form in my view:

```
public class Foo
{  
    public List<Bar> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public List<string> Lines { get; set; }
    public int Resolution { get; set; }
}
```

I am presenting this information to the user as various groups of RadioFields.

How do I bind the RadioFields so that they display a group of RadioFields for each item in Items. Each group of RadioFields having an option for each Lines and that each group of RadioFields is bounded to Resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a plain old HTML question

```
<% foreach (var bar in view.Foo.Items) { %>
   <% var barIx = 0; %>
<fieldset>
   <% foreach (var line in bar.Lines) { %>
     <% var lineIx = 0; %>
   <label for="bar<%=barIx%>_line_<%=lineIx%>"><%=line%>: </label>
   <input type="radio" value="<%=line%>" name="bar[<%=barIx%>].Lines" id="bar<%=barIx%>_line_<%=lineIx%>" />
     <% ++lineIx; %>
   <% } %>
   <label for="bar<%=barIx%>_resolution">Resolution: </label>
   <input type="text" value="<%=bar.Resolution%>" name="bar[<%=barIx%>].Resolution" id="bar<%=barIx%>_resolution" />
   <% ++barIx; %>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```